# A question about a proof of Proth's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

This theorem is

> The number $N=2^n\cdot k+1$ with $k<2^n$ is prime if and only if there exists $a$ with $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1\mod N$

[This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2916522) is

> $\Longrightarrow$ :
> If $N$ is prime, let $a$ be a primitive root of $N$.
>
> Fermat's little theorem gives $a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ , hence $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv \pm1\mod N$.
>
> But since $a$ is a primitive root , we cannot have $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 1\mod N$
>
> $\Longleftarrow$ :
> Now suppose, there exists $a$ with $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1\mod N$.
>
> Let $s$ be the order of $a$ modulo $N$, in other words the smallest positive integer with $a^s\equiv 1\mod N$.
>
> Since $a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ , we have $s\mid N-1$
>
> If we write $s=2^m\cdot p$ with odd $p$ , we cannot have $m<n$ because then we would have $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 1\mod N$ because $s$ would divide $(N-1)/2$.
>
> Hence $s$ is at least $2^n$.
>
> If $q$ is a prime factor of $N$, we have $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod q$ because $a$ and $q$ must be coprime, and $s$ must be the order of $a$ modulo $q$, otherwise $s$ would not be the order of $a$ modulo $N$.
>
> Hence, we have $s|q-1$. So, $q>s$.
>
> Since $s$ is at least $2^n$ and $k<2^n$, we can conclude that every prime factor $q$ of $N$ must exceed $\sqrt{N}$ and this implies that $N$ must be prime.

I'm trying to understand this step:

> If $q$ is a prime factor of $N$, we have $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod q$ because $a$ and $q$ must be coprime, and $s$ must be the order of $a$ modulo $q$, otherwise $s$ would not be the order of $a$ modulo $N$.

I know that $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$ is because "$a$ and $q$ are coprime" (since $a$ and $N$ are coprime).

But I don't know how "$s$ must be the order of $a$ modulo $q$" is deduced from "otherwise $s$ would not be the order of $a$ modulo $N$".

I think
$a^s\equiv1\pmod N⇒a^s\equiv1\pmod q⇒s$ is a multiple of the order of $a$ modulo $q$
which doesn't imply that $s$ is equal to the order of $a$ modulo $q$.

E.g. $5$ is a prime factor of $35$.
The order of $2$ modulo $35$ is $12$,
the order of $2$ modulo $5$ is $4$, and $12\ne4$.

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't have $N=2^n\cdot k+1,$ with $k\lt2^n$ though. 

$35$ doesn't meet that criteria.

Comment: @insomesense Yes, it is only a counterexample of a step, not a counterexample of the theorem.

Comment: Well then you're correct.    But the deduction step is done under certain hypotheses.

Comment: @insomesense Yes, the sentence didn't mention how to use the hypotheses, so I'm confused.

Comment: This gives us something to work on.   I'm still looking it over.   BTW there's a typo.    You transposed $a$ and $N, $ I'll fix it.

Comment: There's a proof on page $52$ of Ribenboim, according to Wikipedia.   Maybe look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would rewrite the part of the referenced proof which you question . . .

Assume $N=2^n\cdot k+1$ with $k<2^n$.

We can assume $k$ is odd since that would only increase $n$ and decrease $k$.

Now suppose $a$ is such that $a^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;N)$.

Let $q$ be a prime factor of $N$, and let $s$ be the order of $a$ mod $q$.

Then $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;q)$, hence $s{\,\mid\,}(q-1)$.

But from
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
a^{(N-1)/2}&\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;N)\\[4pt]
a^{N-1}&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;N)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
we get
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
a^{(N-1)/2}&\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;q)\\[4pt]
a^{N-1}&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;q)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence $s{\,\mid\,}(N-1)$ but $s{\,\not\mid\,}\bigl((N-1)/2\bigr)$

It follows that $2^n{\,\mid\,}s$.

To explain the above claim, write $s=2^mj$, where $j$ is odd.

Then from $s{\,\mid\,}(N-1)$ we get
\begin{align*}
&
(2^mj){\,\mid\,}(2^nk)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2^m{\,\mid\,}2^n
\;\text{and}\;
j{\,\mid\,}k
&&
\bigl(\,
\text{since $k$ is odd}
\,\bigr)
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m\le n
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and from $s{\,\not\mid\,}\bigl((N-1)/2\bigr)$ we get
\begin{align*}
&
(2^mj){\,\not\mid\,}(2^{n-1}k)
&&
\bigl(\,
\text{since $(N-1)/2=2^{n-1}k$}
\,\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2^m{\,\not\mid\,}2^{n-1}
&&
\bigl(\,
\text{since $j{\,\mid\,}k$}
\,\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m > n-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m\ge n
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus $m=n$, so $2^n{\,\mid\,}s$, as claimed.

Then $\sqrt{N} < 2^n\le s\le(q-1) < q$.

Comment: You should *prove* the  claim "it follows that $\,2^n\mid s".\ $ Btw, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I've edited in an explanation.